# Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT on USB drive after trying to install Ubuntu on legacy boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb-installation

Tried to reinstall ubuntu on dell latitude e7240
After turning my USB to a bootable device following the tutorial
tried to install and got a *"load kernel.."* error tried to fix the error and ended up getting:
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: ERROR
Main partition table: OK
Backup partition table: OK

---

Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.

---

The operation has completed successfully.

Comment: I have the same model of Dell, and should be able to help you. Is the problem with your USB drive (only), or is there also a problem with the internal drive? Or did you install from one USB drive (live drive) to another USB drive (target for the installation)?

Comment: @sudodus There's a problem with the USB drive and the internal SSD also has a problem since whenever I boot from the internal HardDisk I always get an "..invalid partition table.." since i tried to make the computer dual bootable and which i bypass by clicking any key, hence the need to try and install Ubuntu to take up the whole HardDisk

Comment: My Latitude is complaining "Invalid partition table!" when I boot via F12 from USB in legacy boot mode. I think it is a bug in the UEFI/BIOS system, and there is really nothing wrong with the boot media or operating system. It is not necessary to let Ubuntu take up the whole HDD. It should be as easy as in other computers to install Linux systems alongside each other. If Windows is involved, it is best to start with Windows because otherwise it destroys the Linux [via grub] booting. I have also installed two systems alongside each other in a Dell Precision with a very similar UEFI/BIOS system.

Comment: I use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create USB boot drives with Ubuntu and Ubuntu community flavours. Now that the e7240 is getting older, I think it is a good idea to use Lubuntu (I have version 22.04 LTS installed now). - I can boot both in UEFI mode and legacy mode (and therefore also install in both boot modes). I suggest that you try that too :-)